# How to concatenate two strings and omit possible duplicate sentence?

Tags: javascript, string

I'm working on a speech to text module and, often enough, we have the following scenario:

```js
var str1 = "It was great, I finally had some time to"
var str2 = "had some time to relax and catch up on my reading."
```

I need a function that will go through `str1` backwards and detect if it has a duplicated sentence from `str2` to combine without repeating it, into a concise final phrase like:

```js
var result = "It was great, I finally had some time to relax and catch up on my reading."
```

This is my attempt:

```js
function formPhrase(str1, str2) {
  const words1 = str1.split(' ');
  const words2 = str2.split(' ');

  const uniqueWords = [];

  for (const word of words1) {
    if (!uniqueWords.includes(word)) {
      uniqueWords.push(word);
    }
  }

  for (const word of words2) {
    if (!uniqueWords.includes(word)) {
      uniqueWords.push(word);
    }
  }

  const result = uniqueWords.join(' ');

  return result;
}

var str1 = "It was great, I finally had some time to"
var str2 = "had some time to relax and catch up on my reading."

console.log(formPhrase(str1, str2))
```

It does work for `str1` and `str2`, but if the concatenated area has words that is also included on other parts of `str1` and `str2`, it will fail, example: `this code transforms this` and `transforms this string`.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @mykaf I just added my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you can try using the following function:

```
function removeCommonSubstring(str1, str2) {
    // Initialize the combinedString with str1
    var combinedString = str1;

    // Loop through str2 from the end and check if it's a suffix of 
    combinedString
    for (var i = str2.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (combinedString.endsWith(str2.substring(0, i))) {
        // Remove the common suffix from combinedString and concatenate str2
        combinedString = combinedString.slice(0, combinedString.length - i) + str2;
          break; // Stop after the first match to avoid duplicates
        }
    }

  return combinedString;
}
```

Comment: This does work for my edge case! Thanks! Just fyi, if str1 and str2 does not have a common substring, it will concatenate them without a space.

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano it could join also words in expected mannater but you probably need phrases

Answer (score 0):

Find the longest phrase from the beginning of the second sentence that the first sentence ends with. We slice phrases by spaces with regex:

```js
var str1 = "It was great, I finally had some time to"
var str2 = "had some time to relax and catch up on my reading."

const combine = (str1, str2) => {
  for(const m of str2.matchAll(/\W/g)){
    if(str1.endsWith(str2.slice(0, m.index))){
      return str1 + str2.slice(m.index);
    }
  }
  throw new Error('Cannot combine');
};

console.log(combine(str1, str2));
```

Comment: Could you explain how this works?

Comment: @MaurícioGiordano updated with a new fast version and added a benchmark against Arjun's solution

Comment: Have you tried using i.e: `const str1 = "It was nice nice"; const str2 = "nice nice indeed";`?

Comment: Have you tried using i.e: `const str1 = "It was great"; const str2 = "great, I think";` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan tried to fix with regexp

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that handles fusing two strings, and also the needed concatenation with a *space*:

```js
const fuse = (a, b, x = 0) => {
  b.matchAll(/\W|$/g).forEach(({index: i}) => a.slice(-i) === b.slice(0, i) && (x = i));
  return a + (a && b && !x ? " " : "") + b.slice(x);
};


// Test samples:
console.log(fuse("It was great, I finally had some time to", "had some time to relax and catch up on my reading.")); // "It was great, I finally had some time to relax and catch up on my reading."
console.log(fuse("It was nice nice", "nice nice indeed")); // "It was nice nice indeed"
console.log(fuse("It was great", "great, I think")); // "It was great, I think"
console.log(fuse("a z", "z")); // "a z"
console.log(fuse("a", "z")); // "a z"
console.log(fuse("a", "")); // "a"
console.log(fuse("", "z")); // "z"
console.log(fuse("", "")); // ""
```